# mysql backup error using mysqldump

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a mysql database with the name "BooksDB" and i want to take a backup file
i'm using mysqldump

i write the line below:
c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>

```
mysqldump -uroot -pbooks booksDB >  BackupFile.sql
```

but I got the message :

```
Access is denied
```

where is the problem?
and is it the best way to backup file? i'm using c# in my project

Comment: Are you using Windows 8? Did you try to open the command prompt as administrator?

Comment: oops it works with "run as administrator"..i'm using windows 7
thanks :)